# Getting stored values from NSSet which was fretched from core data as to-many

Tags: core-data, xcode5

I am actually new to iPhone programming and have successfully create an app but I can't figure out how to retrieve the values stored in NSSet. I have 2 entities in core data related to each other. Users one-to-many to Scores. Users entity has firsNname and lastName attributes and Scores entity has onTime, wasAbsent, and dateIn attributes. I fetch using predicate based on firstName and lastName and then execute the fetch. The fetch is successful and I am able to get both entities in one fetch call. However I cannot get values for the values from Scores entity. Whatever I do, it always returns NSSet object. What I want to do is to retrieve the boolean value which was stored in onTime and wasAbsent attributes and feed them to UISwitch.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObject = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname == %@ AND lastname == %@", @"James", @"Smith"];

NSError *error = nil;
self.scoresArray = [self.managedObject executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if ([self.scoresArray count]) {

    Student *student = [self.scoresArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSSet *score = student.scores;
    NSArray *arr = [score allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@", [arr objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

if I can directly access the Score entity instead of using NSSet, that would be ideal that way I can reference it using a dot notation.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like the following:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstname == %@ AND lastname == %@", @"James", @"Smith"];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *studentArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (Student *student in studentArray) {

    Student *student = [self.studentArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@" student is %@ %@", student.firstname, student.lastname);

    for (Score *score in student.scores) {
       // Do something with score
      NSLog(@"   score is %@", score);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am able to retrieve the Scores values. However, my problem is that when values are retrieved, they are retrieved in NSSet data type and what I need is to get the boolean type.

Comment: Your technique worked and it's working now. I able to retrieve the values in boolean as well. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @EdwardB. if it worked you should accept the answer by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Because Student has to-many relationship to Scores (and the property for it is `scores`), when you get the value of `student.scores`, it returns an unordered collection, which is NSSet in Foundation. So you just work with it like you work with NSSet and with collections in general.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am able to retrieve the scores values. However, my problem is that when values are retrieved, their data type is NSSet and I need is to get the boolean type.

Comment: Do you need a collection of booleans? You wrote that the relationship from User to Scores is a to-many relationship.

Comment: The relationship is to-many and few of the entities had attributes which accepted booleans. I saved those boolean values but could not retrieve them back as booleans. I actually got it to work with Ducan's help. If you have a different approach than the one shown by Ducan, I would love to see that. Thanks for your help.